# Disabling ALT - TAB only while a specific application is running using auto hot key

Tags: autohotkey, alt-tab

Id like to be able to run an `.exe` that launches a game, disables the use of Alt-Tab(Preferably only when the game is in focus), then waits for me to exit the game manually before terminating the script.

So far all I have is

```
run C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive
```

!Tab::return

But I can't seem to figure out how to disable it only when the screen is focused on the game, or how to wait for me to close the game before re-enabling it.

Also I'm not entirely sure if this would allow me the use of tab while Im playing the game. I want to be able to press ALT and TAB at the same time as they both have functions, just not switch windows.

Comment: Have a look at [#IfWinActive](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm). Use the Window Spy that comes with AHK to find out a suitable identifier for your window. Usually, the window class (`ahk_class`) is the most suitable. Also, per se it is not possible that a window does different things for one hotkey (like `ALT+TAB`). In your case, it's switching the window, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it. As MLC said use [#ifWinActive](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)

```
;run your program, save the proccess ID
Run, notepad, , , thePid
;add that process to a group
GroupAdd, blockAltTab, % "ahk_pid " thePid
;wait for the process to close and exit
Process, waitClose, %thePid%
ExitApp

;if a window from the blockAltTab group is in the foreground then block alt+tab
#IfWinActive, ahk_group blockAltTab
!Tab::return
;clear the blockAltTab group restriction for any other hotkeys
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: That works inasmuch as it blocks Alt+Tab. Is there a way to have the key apply in the window but not outside of it? Like let's say you're running Windows 3.1 in a DOSBox session and you want to Alt+Tab inside of that but keep host Windows from switching you out of DOSBox itself.

Comment: Okay, I just remapped another key inside DOSBox to do the Alt key and disabled its own function. Much simpler, but only works in sub-environments where you have customizeable keymapping.